# Creating relationship to non-primary column

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I have a table which references a foreign key to its main table. But I want to add an other reference to another table.

For instance, let's suppose I have three tables: `Child, Parent, Transaction`

**Parent table:**

- ParentID

**Child table:**

- ChildID
- ParentID

**Transaction table:**

- TransactionID
- ParentID (references `ParentID on Parent` table, ***nullable***)
- ChildID (references `ChildID on Child` table, ***nullable***)

I want to add a *`cascade on update`* reference to `ParentID on Child` table. So that when a relationship changes in parent-child then my `ParentID` on the `Transaction` table will be automatically updated.

Comment: What is the question? Where are you having issues?

Comment: i want to add foreign key like this: `ALTER TABLE [Transaction]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Name] FOREIGN KEY([ParentID])
REFERENCES [Child] ([ParentID]) CASCADE ON UPDATE`

Comment: Why do you need the ParentID in the Transaction table? You can find the parentID with the ChildID in the Child Table.

Comment: @Wim sometimes i need only ParentID so i save only ParentID. And sometimes i need only ChildID so i save only ChildID. If i had only ChildID column, then i wouldnt save ParentID when i need to save only ParentID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, `ParentID` is not the primary key on the `Child` table.

Is this column unique over the whole table?

- If yes: you can define a unique index on `ParentID` on the `Child` table and then add the FK reference to that unique index
- If **NO**: if `ParentID` on `Child` is **not** unique, then you **cannot** create a FK reference to it. The "target" of a FK reference must be either the primary key of that table, or at least a unique column on that table. Otherwise, which row exactly are you referring to if you have `ParentID = 42` and the value is **not** unique?!?!?

> *Simply, I want the same value pair on my ParentID&ChildID columns on Transaction table as ParentID&ChildID columns on Child table*

In that case, you need a FK relation on **both columns** - create it like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UX_ParentChild
ON dbo.Child(ParentID, ChildID)

ALTER TABLE dbo.Transaction
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Transaction_Child
FOREIGN KEY(ParentID, ChildID) REFERENCES dbo.Child(ParentID, ChildID)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Comment: ParentID is not primary key on the Child table but it is foreign key to Parent table. Simply, i want the same value pair on my **ParentID&ChildID columns on Transaction table** as **ParentID&ChildID columns on Child table** how can i achive that?

Comment: i get the following error: **There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'dbo.Child' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_Transaction_Child'.**

Comment: @Fer: you need to creat a **unique index** on those two columns (on the `Child` table) first - if that works, then you can create the FK relationship. Check out my again updated response