# How to create relationship between two non primary key entity in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have few tables where I need to link Patient card ID (PID) of table patient where primary key is patient_id with the PID field of other tables... how can I do that? help!

Comment: Why is the question tagged with `c#`? From what I'm reading, it's a simple sql matter.

Comment: [I hope this helps you][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12895999/1918376

stackoverflow.com/a/12895999/1918376

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can join them like

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Patient] p
INNER JOIN [OtherTable] ot
  ON p.pid = ot.patient_id;
```

Comment: it says "Invalid object name 'tbl_patient'"... actually the name of my table was tbl_patient and as you said I wrote.. SELECT * 
FROM[tbl_patient] p

Comment: `Invalid object name` is not a SQL Error ... just open [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) or [SQL Management Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8961) connect to your database and do the query there before taking it to your developer code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Foreign Keys

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
  any_primary_key INT PRIMARY KEY,
  [other attributes],
  patient_id,    
  FOREIGN KEY (patiend_id) REFERENCES Patients.patient_id
)
```

Where Patients is a table that has the original `patient_id` which has to be declared as `unique`.

Comment: Do I need to declare patient_id unique? I just need to connect "pid" of patient table (tbl_patient) to "pid" of image table (tbl_image)... where "pid" is patient card number whereas patient_id is the primary key with auto increment...

Comment: It really depends on your schema which I'm not getting completely. Your original table which has the value which you want to reference too must have that value as a unique value. The value in table T (which I use as an example) is then only a reference back to that unique value. T can have multiple tuples containing the reference since it has another primary key. I would suggest you sigh up here: https://www.coursera.org/course/db and look at the videos about keys (it's free and great!).